# Serial Port application in console not working

Tags: c#, serial-port, console-application

I am trying to make a `console` application in `c#` that reads `Serial Port` and send data over `TCP` to another machine in network.

I have written the following code

```
class Program
{

    static SerialPort mPort;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        mPort = new SerialPort();
        mPort.BaudRate = 4800;
        mPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        mPort.DataBits = 8;
        mPort.PortName = "COM4";
        if (!mPort.IsOpen)
        {
            mPort.Open();
        }
        mPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(mPort_DataReceived);

    }
    private static void mPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (mPort.IsOpen)
            {

            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
 }
```

but application closed after hitting `mPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(mPort_DataReceived);` line in `static void Main(string[] args)` function.

Why it is not firing `mPort_DataReceived` event ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basic console application behaviour. Just add:

```
    mPort.DataReceived += ...

    /// wait till something happens
    Console.Read();
}
```

at the end of the main method. Then watch your event to get fired.

This approach is only a workaround for that behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
mPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(mPort_DataReceived);
```

is subscribing to the event. But you **never wait** for an event to occure.

After that line, your `Main` method returns. As this is the **main method of your process**, your process **terminates** after `Main` returns.

One simple way to keep the process running is to add something like

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

at the end of `Main`, so your program waits for the user to hit a key before it terminates.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, that your program simply terminates. You need a kind of loop to keep it alive, for example like this. It's running and checking if a key has been pressed, and stopps only if that was 'Escape'.

```
        // Do initialisation work here

        ConsoleKeyInfo cki = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
        do 
        {
            // Do frequently work here

            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                cki = Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
        while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```